# Solve functional equation: $\frac{F(x)}{F(1)} = 2F\left(\frac{(1+x)^2}{4a}\right)-F(x/a)$

Tags: functional-equations, recursion

Solve this functional equation:

$$\frac{F(x)}{F(1)} = 2F\left(\frac{(1+x)^2}{4a}\right)-F(x/a)$$

for $F(x)$ where $a > 0$ is a real parameter. Here $F(x)$ is a real function. The domain of $x$ is an open interval including 0. I do not specify the interval myself because I do not know the radius of convergence. I know there is a trivial constant solution, $F(x) = 1$. Is there a non-constant solution?

I do not know if it has an analytical solution, and have no reason to expect that it does. It showed up in some calculations I was doing. But if there is a technique I can apply, it would be nice to know about it.

Comment: What is the domain?  In every functional equation problem, you should state clearly what the domain is.  Also, which kind of values does this function take (this question is less important than the domain, but should be clarified)?

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks, I did some edits.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually at least one non-constant solution for any given $a > 0$, if you're ready to accept non-continuous solutions (this here answer might thus feel unsatisfying for some since it neither solves the equation nor gives any non-constant *continuous* solution).

Since $x \mapsto 1$ is a solution, we can restrict our search to solutions $F$ such that $F(\mathbb{R}) \subset \{0,1\}$, or equivalently the solutions of the form $F = _A$ for a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$.
(Spoiler: just taking indicator functions worked here, but generally trying to compose or multiply existing or would-be solutions by an indicator function, like $_\mathbb{Q}$, seems surprisingly useful in showing non-uniqueness of solutions of such equations, based on a few other questions I've looked at during this month.)

In order for the equation to even have a sense, we need $1 \in A$, otherwise $F(1)$ would be null. Moreover, it can be shown, through some very light brute-forcing, that we have the following condition:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\quad x \in A \,\,\Leftrightarrow\,\, \frac{x}{a} \in A \,\,\Leftrightarrow\,\, \frac{(1+x)^2}{4a} \in A \tag{1}$$
Conversely, any set $A$ satisfying this condition $(1)$ and such that $1 \in A$ will produce a solution of the equation, and so we have found exactly the solutions such that $F(\mathbb{R}) \subset \{0,1\}$. Let's show there is at least one such set that is not all of $\mathbb{R}$.

We will show something stronger: there exists a field $\mathbb{Q} \subset A \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ for which $(1)$ holds.
To know how to find this $A$, let's first see why looking for a field could be a good idea. Assume for just this paragraph that we have such a field $A$.
Since $1 \in A$, and $ 1 = \frac{a}{a}$, we have: $a \in A$, and as such condition $(1)$ is actually equivalent to:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\quad x \in A \,\,\Leftrightarrow\,\, (1+x)^2 \in A$$
but $1 \in A$ implies $x \in A \Leftrightarrow 1 + x \in A$, therefore the above is again equivalent to, by choosing $y = 1+x$:
$$\forall y \in \mathbb{R},\quad y \in A \,\,\Leftrightarrow\,\, y^2 \in A \tag{1bis}$$
The reason why this is good is that we actually know how to, well, construct (pun intended) a field $\mathbb{Q} \subset A \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ containing a given $a$ and satisfying $(1\text{bis})$: this is done by mimicking the creation of the field of [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number) (I linked the English page since we're on the mostly-English-speaking MSE but I prefer how the [French page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombre_constructible#D%C3%A9finition_d%27un_nombre_constructible) handles the matter so I'll use their notations, sorry... To anyone potentially looking at this post: do not hesitate to edit what's in this parenthesis with a link to an English source defining the constructible numbers in the same way as the French page).

Essentially boils down to: let $E_a := \{(0,0), (1,0), (a,0)\} \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ (basically we only added the point $(a,0)$ compared to the definition of the usual constructible numbers where you start with only $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$), then define $C_n(E_a)$ as the set of points that are constructible from $E_a$ in $n$ steps for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then take $C(E_a) := \bigcup_n C_n(E_a)$, and finally consider $A := \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid (x,0) \in C(E_a)\}$.
By what I'll call "geometry magic" that I'll spare you the details about, $A$ is a field that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $a$, and for every positive element $x$ of $A$, $\sqrt{x}$ also belongs in $A$, which means that $A$ respects the condition $(1\text{bis})$.

It only remains to see that $A$ is not $\mathbb{R}$.
Since $E_a$ is finite, the $C_n(E_a)$ are actually all finite, and the reunion $C(E_a)$, which can be shown to be equal to $A^2$, is thus Lebesgue-negligeable in $\mathbb{R^2}$ as a countable union of countable sets.
In particular, $A^2 \neq \mathbb{R}^2$, granting: $A \neq \mathbb{R}$. Hence, by all the previous observations, $F := _A$ is a solution of our functional equation, and it is non-constant (and non-continuous) due to: $A \not\in \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$.